# How to toggle active/inactive of tabs in Bootstrap using D3.js?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

How can I toggle active/inactive of tabs in Bootstrap using D3.js?

Here's my HTML:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to write the following code:

```js
    d3.select("ul.navbar-nav").on("click", function() {
        d3.select(this).selectAll("li").style("class", "active");
    })
```

In the above code I tried to have it recognize the tap and make it "active" state. However, when I tried to tap one of the tab there, it doesn't work at all.

What's wrong with this code? I just wanted to register `on` function to the `ul.navbar-nav`, and when one of the tab is tapped I want it to be active, and then the other tabs are converted to "inactive".

Comment: `.attr("class","active")`?

Comment: I tried it, but it was not working, either...

Comment: I don't know d3 - but what about native js `.className = 'active'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed my comments and try to give some help here although I don't know anything about d3.js ...

First of all as your HTML snippet shows just plain-text but no HTML at all I need to guess about your DOM ... so is the selector correct? Is the click handler called at all?

Assuming it is called, do the `select` and `selectAll` selectors return the desired elements?

If so, my understanding of `.style` function is that it actually sets a CSS property and not a class. Instead `.classed('active', true)` or `.classed('active', false)` are what I found when I googled "d3 add css class".

While this may set the class properly you still need to remove the active class from other tabs to make it work.

If this still does not work you may try using the bootstrap `.tab('show')` method ... does d3 interact with jQuery so that the plugin functions work directly on d3 selectors? Does the d3 selector return the node so that you can wrap it like `$(d3.select(this)).tab('show')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the exact same thing with this piece of code. Don't know if this the elegant way doing it or not but it works. This is tried and tested with `d3` and `bootstrap`.

```
var navList = d3.select("ul.navbar-nav");
navList.selectAll("li").on("click", function (d, i) {
    navList.selectAll("li").classed("active", function (e, j) { return j == i; });
});
```